# Firebase Deploy Function and website hosting Error

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

```
i  deploying database, storage, firestore, functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint
npm ERR! path D:\public\$RESOURCE_DIR\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\public\$RESOURCE_DIR
\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bonrix\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-31T07_42_27
_103Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code4294
963238

D:\public>
```

====================================================
Check Attachment[$RESOURCE_DIR folder have no file named package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Z7E.png)

Answer (score 1):

as it show the log, you have no package.json inside your dir. 
btw, you should run it from root of the project with installed firebase-tools globaly via npm. 
Then just do all steps from there (firebase) guide.

Comment: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bajar-today.appspot.com/o/3.png?alt=media&token=04e7c604-b010-46f1-952d-47a4f2981043 ---- Check this image and help me

Comment: check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aICeVhu2mAE

Comment: and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8&t=2s